# Announcing features or changes to users dynamically

Tags: java, api

So we have a web application and we keep changing user interface. Sometimes user asks to tell them about new features and changes. Previously we have sent a group email to let our users know about new features and changes. But email thing is tedious sometimes. Is there any easier way to dynamically announce on everyone's application that these features have been added? Are there any examples , apis for this? I am looking for any apis particularly in Java.

Comment: Would you like people to see that the web app has changed once they have opened it on the browser? Or do you want to announce the changes before so that when they open the webapp they will go looking for these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a page on your web app (like a news/updates/announcements page) for this kind of thing. If you are planning major changes then put an article on the news page a little in advance, maybe with some screenshots, so the users know that change is coming.

When the news page changes (ie you have a new announcement to make) then make the link to the page more obvious, a bit like stackoverflow.com does with the link to the blog page.